# Why is setuid dropped on execve in an alpine container?

Tags: docker, security, rust, system-calls, busybox

In an alpine container only: When running a setuid binary which starts an other executable (`execve(2)`), <strike>the kernel</strike><sup>[1]</sup>  BusyBox seems to drop privileges acquired by setuid. I think this might be by design because of security implications.

*Question*: I would like to understand why this is happening and what is responsible for this?

I am working on a one-shot setuid runner called [`kamikaze`](https://github.com/Enteee/kamikaze) written in `rust`. `kamikaze` is a very simple binary that [`unlink(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink) itself and then starts a new process using [`fork(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [`execve(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

The main components are:

[`src/main.rs` [a47dedc]](https://github.com/Enteee/kamikaze/tree/a47dedc1e7cff10c188383914d707ab38b7a6bdf/src/main.rs): Implements the `unlink(2)` and process spawning.

```rust
use std::env;

use std::fs;

use std::process::{Command, exit};

fn usage() {
    println!("usage: kamikaze <command> <arguments>");
    exit(1);
}

fn main() {

    // Kill myself
    fs::remove_file(
        env::current_exe().expect("failed to get path to executable")
    ).expect("kamikaze failed");

    let mut args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    match args.len() {
        0 => usage(),
        1 => usage(),
        _ => {
            args.remove(0);
            let mut child = Command::new(args.remove(0))
                .args(&args)
                .spawn()
                .expect("failed to execute process");
            exit(
                child
                    .wait()
                    .expect("wait failed")
                        .code().unwrap()
            );
        },
    }

}
```

[`install.sh` [a47dedc]](https://github.com/Enteee/kamikaze/tree/a47dedc1e7cff10c188383914d707ab38b7a6bdf/install.sh): A simple installer which downloads `kamikaze`, changes ownership to `root` and sets the setuid bit.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -euo pipefail
REPO="Enteee/kamikaze"
INSTALL="install -m 755 -o root kamikaze-download kamikaze && chmod u+s kamikaze"

curl -s "https://api.github.com/repos/${REPO}/releases/latest" \
   | grep "browser_download_url" \
   | cut -d '"' -f 4 \
   | xargs -n1 curl -s -L --output kamikaze-download

trap 'rm kamikaze-download' EXIT

if [[ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]]; then
  sudo sh -c "${INSTALL}"
else
  eval "${INSTALL}"
fi
```

When I run `kamikaze` outside a container<sup>[2]</sup>:

```sh
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Enteee/kamikaze/master/install.sh | sh
$ ./kamikaze ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      3223  9587  0 08:17 pts/0    00:00:00 ./kamikaze ps -f
root      3224  3223  0 08:17 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f
```

I get the expected behavior. The child process (`PID=3224`) runs as `root`. On the other hand, inside a container<sup>[2]</sup>:

```sh
$ docker build -t kamikaze - <<EOF
  FROM alpine
  RUN set -exuo pipefail \
    && apk add curl \
    && curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Enteee/kamikaze/master/install.sh | sh

  USER nobody
  CMD ["/kamikaze", "ps"]
EOF
$ docker run kamikaze
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /kamikaze ps
    6 nobody    0:00 ps
```

`ps` runs as `nobody`.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> I first thought that this was because of some security mechanism implemented by docker and the Linux kernel. But after a deep dive into [Docker Security](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/non-events/), [`NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/userspace-api/no_new_privs.html) and [`seccomp(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seccomp.2.html) I finally realized that BusyBox is simply dropping privileges.

<sup>[2]</sup> `kamikaze [1.0.0]` fixed and changed this behavior. Therefore this example does no longer work. For reproducing the example use the [`kamikaze` [0.0.0]](https://github.com/Enteee/kamikaze/releases/tag/0.0.0) release.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning: I first thought that  the privilege  downgrade happens on `fork(2)`, but i implemented [a version of `kamikaze` which should not fork](https://github.com/Enteee/kamikaze/tree/0f81d2e844223a85cd93960cfbc1e667ea4147ad) and I see the same behavior.

Comment: Maybe this part of the man page can explain:

https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve

If the set-user-ID bit is set on the program file pointed to by filename, and the underlying file system is not mounted nosuid (the MS_NOSUID flag for mount(2)), and the calling process is not being ptraced, then the effective user ID of the calling process is changed to that of the owner of the program file. Similarly, when the set-group-ID bit of the program file is set the effective group ID of the calling process is set to the group of the program file.

Comment: Thank you. From what I understand, that section of the man page explains how setuid works. Which is exactly what I see outside the container, but not inside. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Also maybe worth noticing: docker mounts the root file system **without** the nosuid flag:
```$ docker run -ti  alpine sh -c 'mount | grep -i "on / "'``` yields ```overlay on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/GXDHPBDM7TSYZS5OP43RJVSOWM:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/C57DZORPIGMSUEOFG6YYSBNATK,upperdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c9f27caebcbff131d58137067feb75b941b5d7ad4d5677a8140334dce75ad576/diff,workdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c9f27caebcbff131d58137067feb75b941b5d7ad4d5677a8140334dce75ad576/work)```

Comment: There are 3 conditions specified here for setuid to work. You should check if these are different between the regular environment and the container. Specifically what seems most likely is the mount parameters.

Comment: From what I can see, 1. and 2. are met. 1. setuid set = yes, see installer script 2. mount without nosuid = yes, see my last comment. But I am not quite sure if 3. could be triggering the issue. How are processes started when run inside a container?

Comment: One thing to check is the status code after running the commands $?.
Maybe chmod fails or something else

Comment: I don't think that there is an error in `install.sh`. Also:  ```$ docker run kamikaze ls -l kamikaze``` yields ```-rwsr-xr-x    1 root     root        361624 May  1 14:28 kamikaze```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BusyBox, which implements the `ps` command in alpine, drops privileges acquired by setuid by setting the effective user id to the real user id.

[libbb/appletlib.c [b097a84]](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/b097a84d62dcfcf201a695b54bcfafae70cac8a6/libbb/appletlib.c#L677):

```
    } else if (APPLET_SUID(applet_no) == BB_SUID_DROP) {
        /*
         * Drop all privileges.
         *
         * Don't check for errors: in normal use, they are impossible,
         * and in special cases, exiting is harmful. Example:
         * 'unshare --user' when user's shell is also from busybox.
         *
         * 'unshare --user' creates a new user namespace without any
         * uid mappings. Thus, busybox binary is setuid nobody:nogroup
         * within the namespace, as that is the only user. However,
         * since no uids are mapped, calls to setgid/setuid
         * fail (even though they would do nothing).
         */
        setgid(rgid);
        setuid(ruid);
    }
```

[procps/ps.c [b097a84]](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/b097a84d62dcfcf201a695b54bcfafae70cac8a6/procps/ps.c#L53): Defines `BB_SUID_DROP`.

```
//                 APPLET_NOEXEC:name    main location    suid_type     help
//applet:IF_PS(    APPLET_NOEXEC(ps,     ps,  BB_DIR_BIN, BB_SUID_DROP, ps))
//applet:IF_MINIPS(APPLET_NOEXEC(minips, ps,  BB_DIR_BIN, BB_SUID_DROP, ps))
```

The fix for this was simple. `kamikaze` just has to set the real user id to the effective user id before `execve(2)`.

[src/main.rs [f4c5501]](https://github.com/Enteee/kamikaze/blob/f4c5501ec12746d482b37db453691a1be1871e78/src/main.rs):

```
extern crate exec;
extern crate users;

use std::env;

use std::fs;

use std::process::exit;

use users::{get_effective_uid, get_effective_gid};
use users::switch::{set_current_uid, set_current_gid};

fn usage() {
    println!("usage: kamikaze <command> <arguments>");
}

fn main() {

    // Kill myself
    fs::remove_file(
        env::current_exe().expect("failed to get path to executable")
    ).expect("kamikaze failed");

    set_current_uid(
        get_effective_uid()
    ).expect("failed setting current uid");

    set_current_gid(
        get_effective_gid()
    ).expect("failed setting current gid");

    let mut args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    match args.len() {
        0 => usage(),
        1 => usage(),
        _ => {
            args.remove(0);
            let err = exec::Command::new(args.remove(0))
                .args(&args)
                .exec();
            println!("Error: {}", err);
        },
    }
    // Should never get here
    exit(1);
}
```

with the newly released [`kamikaze [1.0.0]`](https://github.com/Enteee/kamikaze/releases/tag/1.0.0) we now get:

```sh
$ docker build -t kamikaze - <<EOF
  FROM alpine
  RUN set -exuo pipefail \
    && apk add curl \
    && curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Enteee/kamikaze/master/install.sh | sh

  USER nobody
  CMD ["/kamikaze", "ps"]
EOF
$ docker run kamikaze
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 ps
```